# Add Reference locating from program

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net when you add a reference, I'm not really sure how it works.  But I'm wondering what happens when I finish the application and want to allow people to use it, how does the add reference work after I complete the app.  Sorry if I sound like an idiot I don't do any programming except for little in spare time.

I guess another way to say the question is, how will the program reference those DLLs when I finish and am ready to hand out the program.  I was planning to store all the DLLs in a folder called files which is in the application startup spot.  How would I say Add the Reference from Application Startup path /files, from the program itself?

I'm not sure if that would be like adding a reference at runtime, I've tried searching but am struggling to figure out exactly how it would work.

Or when I compile the program does it create a new dll file?

And if that's so, how do I make the references go into a folder?

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is what you mean by 'hand out the program'. If you are going to create an installation project then the 'detected dependencies' should automatically populate itself with the appropriate dll's etc and bind these into the .msi without any action on your part.
If you are just going to 'hand out' an exe then you will need to provide the dll's etc too and somehow get them into the same folder as the exe.
Just to complicate matters MS have deprecated their own .msi builder and it's not available in VS2012 (AFAIK - I'm still using VS2010, although I've had a quick look at VS2012 but didn't like what I saw) so you might be looking at Installshield SE etc.